# ora-00913 too many values while using sequence

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

In my table i have used sequence to create id automatically

How to Insert into this table using Netbeans

I tried a code to insert values and got the following error

> [Microsoft] [ODBC driver for Oracle] [Oracle]ORA-00913:too many values

the code is:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try
    {        

    String sql=("insert into customer values(seq_user.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,lname.getText());
    pstmt.setString(2,fname.getText());
    pstmt.setString(3,email.getText());
    pstmt.setString(4,password.getText());
    pstmt.setString(5,address1.getText());
    pstmt.setString(6,address2.getText());
    pstmt.setString(7,city.getText());
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: SQL statement that required two sets of equal values, but you entered more items in the second set than was in the first set. So u have to use column name also if u r not inserting all the columns.

Comment: Then Update the answer and close the question.

Comment: Unrelated but: do not use the JDBC/ODBC bridge. It's buggy and slow. Oracle has a very good native JDBC driver. Use that one